# Pandas: hange value in column by condition with value from the same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, contains

I need to replace in one column named `'month'` values with values from the same column based on other column `'step_name'`. If `df.step_name.str.contains('step1')` I want to use value of `'month'` where `df.step_name.str.contains('step2')`. I used `df.loc[]` but it just remove values of `month` with `'step1'`.

```
for i in set(df['id']): df.loc[(df.id.str.contains(i))&(df.step_name.str.contains('step1')),'month'] = df.loc[(df.id.str.contains(i))&(df.step_name.str.contains('step2')),'month']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the source DataFrame contains:

```
   id step_name     month
0  10     step1   January
1  10     step2     March
2  12     step1  February
3  12     step2     April
4  14     step1       May
```

so that in rows with index *0* and *2* (*step_name == 'step1'*)
*month* column should be updated with values from the next row
(*step_name == 'step2'*, same *id*).

To do it, run:

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df.update(df[df.step_name == 'step2']['month'])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
   id step_name  month
0  10     step1  March
1  10     step2  March
2  12     step1  April
3  12     step2  April
4  14     step1    May
```

Note that *update* actually updates both rows with respective *id*,
but in case of rows with *step_name == 'step2'* nothing gets changed.

In my opinion, my solution is more *pandasonic* than your loop with
separate updates for each *id*.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you did there! It's subtle, a good mistake to make.

First, I'll make a quick cleanup so we can see what's going on:

```
# Your code.
is_step1 = new_df.step_name.str.contains('step1')
is_step2 = new_df.step_name.str.contains('step2')

for i in set(df['id']): 
  is_id = df.id.str.contains(i)
  df.loc[is_id & is_step1, 'month'] = df.loc[is_id & is_step2, 'month']
```

You use two masks wich interact with each other.

```
'''
mask1 mask2  => df[mask1] df[mask2]
1     0         value1    NaN        -> value1 = NaN
0     1         NaN       value2
0     0         NaN       NaN
0     0         NaN       NaN
'''
```

If you use an array instead, pandas will map the array with the values to fill on the left side of the assignment...

```
new_df.loc[is_id & is_step1, 'month'] = new_df.loc[is_id & is_step2, 'month'].values
```

... and this is what happens:

```
'''
mask1 mask2  => df[mask1] df[mask2].values
1     0         value1    value2            -> value1 = value2
0     1         NaN       
0     0         NaN       
0     0         NaN       
'''
```

Now if you want, by example, to swap the month of step1 & step2...

```
# N.B. I don't say it is best practice, but it works!
new_df = df.sort_values('id')

is_step1 = new_df.step_name.str.contains('step1')
is_step2 = new_df.step_name.str.contains('step2')

c = df.loc[is_step1, 'month'].values
new_df.loc[is_step1, 'month'] = new_df.loc[is_step2, 'month'].values
new_df.loc[is_step2, 'month'] = c
```

I believe Valdi_Bo's solution to be the best. Take his answer. ;)